# Create event with the batch files

Tags: file, batch-file, errorlevel

Here's what i want to achieve.  We have this email archive database which we optimize on a weekly basis . At the moment we are manually logging in run the command and monitor the status. The optimization can take anywhere between 3-12 hours which is making us login every few hours and check if it has finished or not etc.
What i want to do is create a batch file and schedule a task to run the batch file. Now when the batch file starts, i event to generate a event ID (and then i can capture this evend id and generate a email via our monitoring sytem) and similarly when the optimization finishes generate event id in the application log. Here what i was thinking of doing:-

```
@echo off
cd C:\Program Files\Quest Software\ArchiveManager
C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /K "Archive Full Text Index Service" –optimize
IF errorlevel 1 Goto Stoppd
exit
:Stoppd
eventcreate /l application /t information /so 9999 /id 1 /d "the optimization has started "
:end
```

I am very bad with batch files and scripts. Can someone please advise on how to generate event.? Thanks

Comment: How are you starting the backup?

Answer (score 1):

First, the `cmd /k` operation should return an `errorlevel` of `0` if it was launched correctly, so your call to `eventcreate` should occur before your `exit` command, not after your `:Stoppd` label as you have it in your example.

Second, if you want to trigger your archive operation to run as a spawned process, you should put `start` in front of the `cmd` line:

```
start C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /K "Archive Full Text Index Service" –optimize
```

This will allow your process to be kicked off and then the current console can continue and trigger your `'archive has started'` event.

Third, in order to get the event to be created after your archive operation finishes, you have a couple choices:

1. you could concat two commands together using `&`:

   ```
   start C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /K "Archive Full Text Index Service" –optimize & eventcreate ...
   ```
2. you could put your archive call and its subsequent eventcreate call in a batch file and then call it in your `cmd /k` call.

   ```
   start C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /K myArchiveAndEventBatch.bat
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Would it be acceptable to not create an event ID and simply use an e-mailing program like [Blat](http://www.blat.net/) to send an e-mail when you want to be warned?